# How to append only new data instead of all?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using ajax time function for keeep ckecking the new data and appending it if new data is found in database.But each half second, the whole data is appended istead of only the new one.Plz help.

Php  function(load.php)

```
 $tocom=$_POST['tocom'];
    $sql=mysqli_query($db3->connection,"SELECT * FROM chat_com where to='$tocom'  ORDER by time DESC");
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){

        $tocomr=$row['tocom'];
        $text=$row['text'];
        echo $text;

    }
```

Ajax function is here.

```
function chat_com_one(id, name) {
$('#chatcom').show('fast');
(function chatcom_load_one(id, name) {
    $.post('load.php', {tocom:id}, function(data) {
        $('#chat_win').append(data);
        setTimeout(chatcom_load_one(id, name), 500);
    });
}(id, name));
```

}

Comment: @Alexander Thats exactly my question.how would I filter between new and old data?

Comment: how about selecting based on date.

Comment: I hope you're not planning on having too many guests performing this operation at the same time. That's quite a bit of querying and hits that your server is going to take. If you're performing this kind of operation you should probably look into long polling in order to reduce the load on the server. Check this out: [Long Polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology)

Answer (score 0):

If do not see any `if()` to check if element is not already added, now `WHERE` clause to limit results from your query. Alternatively just remove old content and put the new one as a whole instead of appending (but this is not effective).

Comment: How the final if() condition will look like?This is exactly my question.I am scracthing my head filtering new and old data>could You plz add if() condition in ans.

Answer (score 0):

Well either you will need to change your SQL statement or don't do an append and just rewrite the whole div.

Comment: Thanks for your response. What to add in new div?Plz eloborate

Answer (score 0):

change `setTimeout` with `setInterval`
and see the changes:

```
function chat_com_one(id, name) {
 $('#chatcom').show('fast');
 (function chatcom_load_one(id, name) {
  $.post('load.php', {tocom:id}, function(data) {
     $('#chat_win').append(data);
     setInterval(chatcom_load_one(id, name), 500);
  });
}(id, name));
```

good luck